# Ivygen update glitch

Tags: add-on

No matter what modifier i try the base ive gen always switches to a single long branch always in a similar configuration to this, this includes just simply pressing the update button a new ivy gen, any help?

Before
[image: fresh ivy gen]
After
[image: fresh ivy gen after pressing update]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: I see maximum time is 0, maybe try to increase that value ?